# Can two pages share same url in liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay

I am developing a website which has tabs and each tab has sub tab. I have used pages to display tabs.I have a problem my content of tab and its first sub tab is same.And i am tring a way through which url could be shared by two. In  control panel you have friendly url when i try to use one url for both-it shows **friendly url has to be unique**. Like TAB_A has TAB_A,TAB_A1,TAB_A2,TAB_A3 as sub pages. And TAB_A(parent page) and TAB_A(child page) should be same.

TAB_A-

- TAB_A
- TAB_A1
- TAB_A2
- TAB_A3

please help if it has themes involved what is to be done.

Comment: Should move this question to liferay forum instead! :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) Here is the link to [Liferay Forums](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can. One of this two pages can be of type "Link to Page".

To make parent page a link to child page:

1. Choose "Control Panel" -> "Site Pages"
2. Choose parent page
3. Choose "Link to page" in the combobox "Type"
4. Choose child page in the appeared combobox "Link to Page"